# Install Ubuntu on a multipath SAN device

Tags: system-installation, multipath

I have tried to install Ubuntu 16.10 on a multipathed SAN device and tried the suggested method as follows:

boot: linux install disk-detect/multipath/enable=true

That doesn't recognize that the two paths are going to the same disk.

Has anyone done this successfully? What is the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this recently using Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server and Cobbler/PXE boot. The kernel options / boot string used is as follows:

```
biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 netcfg/choose_interface=eth0 netcfg/get_hostname=openstack-controller-node install disk-detect/multipath/enable=true
```

This detects the multipath disk and I can partition it fine but there seems to be a bug in grub because it is not installing to the multipath device leaving the server stuck with no way to boot.

EDIT: Managed to get the server booting, I had run grub-install manually:

```
grub-install /dev/mapper/mpatha
```

Hope this helps